# GUI installed app disappears immediately after entering the password, and the desktop icon vanishes too

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

This has been recurring lately, and I can't open the wallet. My Airbook is 10 years old but recently updated. Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Do you run any AV (AntiVirus) software?

Comment: Negative....just the Brave standard package.

Comment: Which version of the GUI are you trying to use? Also, can you list the specific version of your operating system?

Comment: This is the version:Current Version: 0.17.3.2 - Oxygen Orion

Comment: Mac OS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Do you know how to operate the terminal? I think we have to start the GUI in low graphics mode, hence my question.